# Solve using Quadratic formula, or inferring?

Tags: quadratics, curves

Given curve:
$y = \frac{1}{4} x^2 + 2x + 3$
and associated table of values:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | -8 | -6 | -4 | -2 | 0 | 2 |
| y | 3 | 0 | -1 | 0 | 3 | 8 |

Write down one solution of:
**$\frac{x}{2}+2 = \frac{1}{4} x^2 + 2x + 3$**

- Do we rearrange and use the quadratic formula, $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a}$, to find a solution?
- Or can we infer/derive a solution from the table of values?

Comment: Unfortunately, the solutions are $-3\pm \sqrt{5},$ therefore it seems that the use of the table or the curve and straightline is not possible. Similarly, the fact that the left side is derivative of the right side doesn't help. I would use the formula with discriminant.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you.

Comment: The fornula works all the times if roots are real or non-real, integer, rational or irrational where as table method will work when roots are integer.